# R - create incrementing column based on id occurencies

Tags: r, count, dataframe, increment

I am quite new to R and need some help with a task. My dataframe data1 looks something like that:

```
ID    Action
A1    A
A1    E
A2    B
B1    A
B2    C
B2    D   
B2    A
B3    E
```

I need to create a new column Sequence, which increments based on the ID and basically tells me, how often an Action was beeing performed on this ID at that time. For a new ID it would start again from 1. It would look something like that:

```
ID    Action  Sequence
A1    A       1
A1    E       2
A2    B       1
B1    A       1
B2    C       1
B2    D       2
B2    A       3
B3    E       1
```

I already tried searching for a similar problem, but could just find solutions, where the number of occurencies was counted without incrementing.

It would be great if you could help me

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getanID` from `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
 getanID(df, 'ID')
 #     ID Action .id
 #1: A1      A   1
 #2: A1      E   2
 #3: A2      B   1
 #4: B1      A   1
 #5: B2      C   1
 #6: B2      D   2
 #7: B2      A   3
 #8: B3      E   1
```

Or `ave` from `base R`

```
transform(df, Sequence=ave(seq_along(ID), ID, FUN=seq_along))
#    ID Action Sequence
#1 A1      A        1
#2 A1      E        2
#3 A2      B        1
#4 B1      A        1
#5 B2      C        1
#6 B2      D        2
#7 B2      A        3
#8 B3      E        1
```